# PHP array determined with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a problem with complicated JS determination of exact item:

this PHP/SQL code:

```
$prod = array();
$vys = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM produkty ORDER BY nazev");
while ($arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($vys)) {
   $prod[$arr['id_typu']][] = "<option value='".$arr['id_produktu']."'>".$arr['nazev']."</option>";
   $polozky[$arr['id_typu']]= '<select name=idp[]>' . implode(' ', array_values($prod[$arr['id_typu']])) . '</select>';
}
```

this JS code:

```
   <script type=\"text/javascript\">
    function polozky(divName, typ){
            var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
            newdiv.innerHTML = \" $polozky[1] \"
            document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
    }
    </script>
```

and this HTML code:

```
<form method='post'><fieldset>
   <button type='button' name='typ' value='1' onclick=\"polozky('dynamicInput', '1');\">Add produkty from cathegory 1</button>              
   <button type='button' name='typ' value='2' onclick=\"polozky('dynamicInput', '2');\">Add produkty from cathegory 2</button>              
   <button type='button' name='typ' value='3' onclick=\"polozky('dynamicInput', '3');\">Add produkty from cathegory 3</button>              
   <div name='dynamicInput'></div>
</fieldset></form>
```

The problem is, that for each cathegory I want to generate (for every value of button) its own content. Using that `$polozky[1-3]` I'm querying the database for the right items of that cathegory (for items `WHERE id_type=value in bracket`). And I can't imagine that for 100 cathegories, I need to manually insert 100 times `$polozky[1-100]`. There must be some trick to do this. Somehow to store the value or some usage of that parameter (i was thinking of some $num=typ inside of the JS branch, but it's not possible due to the different processing type of JS and PHP).

Do you know, what to do please? ;) Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to query the database after one of the buttons are clicked or are you trying to query the database when the page initially loads

Comment: @ddelnano: I'm querying the database when the page initially loads – and in the JavaScript, I'm only getting the correct stored array of option on it's index (on id_type). I only can't transmit the parameter of JS function to the $polozky[ here ] which makes me confused :( I thought there exists some way when I press the button, to fill some php variable, which then I can use in JS code like $polozky[$type] that would be awesome :(

Comment: check my answer and see if that is what you are trying to do.  My answer will give you the html you want as in your post with the product information inside the button tag.  But I am not sure what you are trying to do with the "onclick" on each button

Comment: instead of telling me what your trying to do with the variables what do you want to happen when a button is clicked

Comment: @ddelnano: Thanks.. Check my comment to you answer please. The onclick function makes the major work in the code. It should return a new elements, which consist of its own, particular (for every number-id_type) content. E.G. Buttons are names of the types of animals, and when I click i.e. Birds (button), the new select with just birds options is generated (it specifies the id_type in the query).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    document.getElementsByTagName("button").onclick = function() {

    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');

     newDiv.innerHTML = this.innerHTML; //Puts text from button inside new Div


document.getElementById('divId').appendChild(newDiv); 
}    
</script>
```

I think this is what you are looking for.  When a button is clicked you want to have a function that executes that will take the current text enclosed by the button, add it  to a newly created `div` and append that to the page.  You also need to give your last `div` an ID of "divId".

Comment: $ddelnano: This seems very fine buddy, but I'm not sure if you understand me correctly. Imho, I think the code you've posted "just" gives an "array" of buttons, which I'm not having a problem with. The problem is in the latter code – in determining, which button was pressed, so its own content can be generated due to the particular button. This inserts "only" buttons, but it looks like an cool alternative to the JS function 'polozky(,)' which I'm using.

Comment: I just realized you would still need the code I posted before in addition to this. Did this help?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It maybe helped. Finally, I solved it like this: <button with onclick=\"polozky('dynamicInput', this) and defined value and in latter code, JS like this `function polozky(divName, typ){
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    switch (typ.value)
    {
    case '1':
            newdiv.innerHTML = \"$polozky[1]\"
            break;           
    case '2': 
            newdiv.innerHTML = \"$polozky[2]\"
            break;  
    case '3':
            newdiv.innerHTML = \"$polozky[3]\"
            break;  
    }
    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);`

Comment: Ok sorry I wasn't really getting at what you wanted.  I never keep the "onclick" functions inside my HTML I always pull them out and bind them to whatever tags I want inside my `script` tags but i appreciate marking my answer as correct I tried as best as I could. Glad you got it working